# Sql query not giving desire result for android application?

Tags: android, sql

I have two tables naming :

1. Custom_fields      -->(id,name,sequence)
2. Custom_field_value -->(id,user_id,custom_field_id,custom_field_value)

The primary key of Custom_fields table is present in Custom_field_value table.Every user will have data associated with custom fields but not for all the fields.I need to make a query to find out the values of custom fields for a particular user id.For every user I need all custom field and their values(even if value is not present).I created the following query:

```
"SELECT alumni_custom_fields. _id,
        alumni_custom_fields.field_label as key ,
        alumni_custom_field_data.custom_field_value as value 
FROM alumni_custom_fields LEFT JOIN alumni_custom_field_data 
ON alumni_custom_fields._id=alumni_custom_field_data.custom_field_id " +
                "WHERE alumni_id ='"+alumniId+"'  order by sequence";
```

But its only giving the custom fields which has value and not giving me the custom fields whose value is none or empty.

Please help me fix this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.....

```
SELECT alumni_custom_fields. _id,alumni_custom_fields.field_label as key ,alumni_custom_field_data.custom_field_value as value FROM alumni_custom_fields LEFT JOIN alumni_custom_field_data ON alumni_custom_fields._id=alumni_custom_field_data.custom_field_id and alumni_id ='"+alumniId+"' order by sequence
```

This will surely solve your problem...

Comment: wow I just need to add AND instead of WHERE clause.Thank Tanrich for help.